# Hauppauge HVR 1600 cannot get it to work

Tags: mythbuntu

I'm new to this forum as well as Linux, I've been using Windows since 1993 and want to do a change. I've been trying Linux many times before but I had to go back to Windows because I couldn't get my TV card to work in Linux.

I've tried again for the past 4 weeks but again cannot get it to work. Here's the Linux Distros I tried, Ubuntu, Mythbuntu, Fedora, Mythfedora, Debian Wheezy, Linux Mint and now I'm trying again with Ubuntu.

Can anybody would be kind enough to help me out with this. I would really like to make this work and switch to Linux once and for all.

Cheers,

Michel :)

Comment: Since I switched to Linux, I use TV-Viewer which worked at once (with another Hauppauge TV card). According to this site, your model is supported as well: http://tv-viewer.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php/Documentation:Installation#Supported_hardware. Although it is not a debian installer package and you first have to install some dependencies, Installation instructions are clear and simple as written in the README file. I will only make it an answer if it works for you, let me know. Download link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tv-viewer/?source=typ_redirect

Answer (score 0):

I had my Hauppauge HVR-1600 card working fine with Mythbuntu 12.04 LTS, but had a devil of a time getting it to work with Mythbuntu 14.04 LTS.

I discovered that there was no driver being set up in /dev for the card. There should be a file /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0.  If it's not there, you won't be able to set up the card in Mythbuntu Backend Setup.

I suggest you go to: http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers and follow the instructions there.  You can follow the Basic Approach - no need to follow the Developers Approach.  I know it looks daunting, but take it a step at a time and it will work for you.

You can list modules loaded from the command line with the command lsmod.  You should see dvb_core, v42_common, and other modules that reference "cx18" when things load correctly. (Conexant CX234**18** is a chip used in the HVR-1600 card).

You can find information on the setting up the HVR-1600 card at: http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Hauppauge_HVR-1600#Backend_Setup.  There is also lots of useful general information on the card on this web page.